# decoding WINDOWS-1255 in a UTF-8 document

Tags: javascript, encoding, decodeuricomponent

I have a content that is generated via javascript and deployed in an iframe.
im giving this code to clients to generate the contet in their site (like a widget)

problem i encounter is that all my documents are encoded with UTF-8 while some of my clients are using Windows-1255 encoding (hebrew)

this of course is not working well with my script and causes various problems.

problem is divided to 2 :
1. data that is transffered from the parent to the server (through the iframe) is not recognized well

1. messages and data sent from the iframe is also not decoded (such as alerts and confirm messages)

i have tries decoding strings using  `decodeURI` and `decodeURIComponent` but its not working.

what can i do to solve this ?

Comment: This one has worked for me in the past, but I haven't tried it for iframe. You can try it if you want: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36343/Decoding-the-Windows-1255-format

Comment: Windows-1255 is a lower character set. I don't think that is possible . However the reverse should be possible.